# Long running queries causes PG POD MASTER 0 (StatefulSet) to reach MAX CORES

Tags: typescript, postgresql, kubernetes, sequelize.js, k3s

I'm running My Backend on a physical machine as follows:

- Backend Code in **TypeScript**
- ORM is **Sequelize**
- Kubernetes: **K3S** version **v1.23.14+k3s1** (c62b03fb) go version go1.17.13

My Backend is running `2` PG PODS (Stateful Set) with the following settings:

```
      volume:
        size: 2500Gi
      numberOfInstances: 2
      postgresql:
        parameters:
          effective_cache_size: "105GB"
          effective_io_concurrency: "200"
          listen_addresses: '*'
          log_destination: "stderr"
          logging_collector: "false"
          log_line_prefix: '%t [%p]: [%l-1] [trx_id=%x] user=%u,db=%d'
          log_min_error_statement: "DEBUG1"
          log_error_verbosity: "verbose"
          maintenance_work_mem: "2GB"
          max_connections: "4000"
          max_wal_size: "16GB"
          min_wal_size: "4GB"
          max_worker_processes: "18"
          max_parallel_workers_per_gather: "9"
          max_parallel_workers: "18"
          max_parallel_maintenance_workers: "4"
          random_page_cost: "1.1"
          shared_bufIfers: "35GB"
          shared_preload_libraries: "pg_stat_statements"
          synchronous_commit: "false"
          syslog_facility: "LOCAL0"
          syslog_ident: "postgres"
          syslog_sequence_numbers: "true"
          syslog_split_messages: "true"
          wal_buffers: "16MB"
          work_mem: "300kB"
          checkpoint_completion_target: "0.9"
      resources:
        limits:
          cpu: 20000m
          memory: 140Gi
        requests:
          cpu: 20000m
          memory: 140Gi
```

After around 2 Hours of running stress on the Backend , when I run the following PSQL Code:

```
SELECT
  pid,
  user,
  pg_stat_activity.query_start,
  now() - pg_stat_activity.query_start AS "QueryRunningTime",
  query,
  state,
  wait_event_type,
  wait_event
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE (now() - pg_stat_activity.query_start) > interval '5 minutes'
ORDER BY "QueryRunningTime" DESC;
```

I get queries that take very long , such as :

```
pid              | 5537
user             | postgres
query_start      | 2023-01-02 13:15:45.801772+00
QueryRunningTime | 00:38:24.34075
query            | INSERT INTO "employeesDetails" ("deviceId","employeeId","depId","version","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES (............... ,'2023-01-02 13:15:45.824 +00:00','2023-01-02 13:15:45.824 +00:00') ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING "deviceId","employeeId","depId","version","createdAt","updatedAt";
state            | idle
wait_event_type  | Client
wait_event       | ClientRead
```

This query took around `00:38:24.34075` Minutes which is a crazy amount of time.

The PG Pool for each POD is:

```
sequelize:
  pool:
    max: 30
    min: 10
    evict: 1000
    idle: 5000
    acquire: 10000
```

Why is this happening , what makes the queries to run this long even though Sequelize uses the above params ?

It causes my PG to reach MAX Cores after around 3-6 Hours of running.

Comment: "state            | idle", this query isn't doing anything, it's idle. Offtopic: work_mem: "300kB" is extremely low.

Comment: @FrankHeikens: It stays alive and kills my POD's CPU , reached its MAX.